# Are there any Haskell specific tools that can show source code from imported modules?

Tags: haskell, ide, cabal

How can I browse Haskell source code preferably without internet connection? Right now I click through hackage search results, click source link and search the source page. There are two problems:

- I'm using current version as a proxy of what I have locally
- This does not work recursively well (another clicks and searches for next definition)

Usually IDEs let you download sources for any library and open new editor tab with definition. I prefer reading code than documentation, less surprises along the way and I can learn something from them.

So, how can I setup for recursive source searches using Haskell tools or standard GNU tools if necessary? All I know right now is that I can generate ctags for vim but where does cabal store sources?

Comment: On my system cabal stores source code in `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/package-name/version/package-name-version.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the opinionated workflow I follow to render the documentation with the source link enabled.

```
$ cd <package-name>
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-documentation --haddock-hyperlink-source
$ cabal configure --enable-documentation --haddock-hyperlink-source
$ cabal haddock --hyperlink-source
$ firefox dist/doc/html/<package-name>/index.html
```

The `Source` link should be enabled for all packages, including the dependencies, as long as they are installed in the sandbox.

In the particular case of Arch Linux, the distro I use, I try to avoid installing Haskell system packages through `pacman` because, by default, the documentation is not built with the source link enabled. In Arch Linux you can use [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Abs) and modify the PKGBUILD with the parameters described above. I'm pretty sure something similar could be done in other distros, but have no idea about Windows or Mac OS X.

It's also worth mentioning that you don't need to type those parameters every time you run `cabal`. You can enable them by default in your `.cabal/config`

This should work without the sandbox but if you are dealing with more than one Haskell project I strongly recommend to use sandboxes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've found it a pain to not have local docs. Seems odd to someone from a Perl background that installing a package wouldn't install the docs.

Comment: I don't intend to start flame war, but this is why it is more convenient to use Gentoo-based distros rather than Arch. You may choose to build documentation for all haskell packages and so on.

Comment: @user2894391, I haven't tried Gentoo yet, but I should definitely try it some day to see how it handles Haskell dependencies. I'm not entirely satisfied with `cabal sandbox` and have tried `nix` but I still don't find it smooth enough.

10 years I was certain by 2014 all these dependency/build issues would be history, but the very same problems remain largely untouched. And this is not a rant on Haskell, it happens, to some extent, in pretty much every language ecosystem.

Comment: Good thing about Gentoo is what one haven't to build everything as rumors suggest. For example I use binary overlay known as 'Calculate Linux' for basic needs and still have ability to use 'haskell' overlay which contains auto-generated ebuilds for all hackage packages.  It's pretty handy.